What does "dub" mean in "Nate Silver dubs presidential race a ‘toss-up’"?
What does dub mean in

Nate Silver dubs presidential race a ‘toss-up’

the title in The Hill?
The closest meaning that I have found in Merriam-Webster is

to call by a distinctive title, epithet, or nickname
Critics have


to dub: to give a man the rank of knight, an honour given by a British king or queen, in a special ceremony that involves touching his shoulders with a sword. By extension, to give an unofficial name or nickname to. In your cited context it's really just a slightly pretentious alternative to Nate Silver calls [the] presidential race a ‘toss-up’ (more idiomatically, Nate Silver says the presidential race is a ‘toss-up’). Very few people ever use dub like this in spoken contexts.

@FumbleFingers - I was dubbed 'Mad Harvey' at my secondary school, and at my advanced age I don't feel any shame, language-related or otherwise in telling people this using those words. My wife said 'Your schoolfellows were perceptive, then'

The unusual usage might be explained partly because headlines often favor short, punchy words, a tradition coming both from the need to conserve space in a column of newsprint and a desire to quickly grab reader attention. You'll notice that the word is only used in the headline, not the body of the article.

@AndyBonner: That might be the same reason newspapers always say some politician vows to do (or not do) something. Again, you almost never hear native speakers use vow in conversations.

@FumbleFingers - and they always seem to make bids rather than attempts. My wife said the other day 'I vow to God I'll murder them next door if they don't turn their heavy metal down'.

@MichaelHarvey: Is your wife a newspaper hack journo? (It's a shiboleth! :)

@FumbleFingers - I still chuckle over London local newspaper that ran a story about a senior church figure who came to grief leaving a party, due to intoxication - the headline was 'After Birthday Bash, The Bishop Falls Into Taxi.' It seems to be a UK male journo game to sneak those three words into a headline, story or opinion piece.

to dub is often used in journalism and no one is answering this. To dub someone something to call them that. I think all these comments between respondents a bit much. You are not helping the OP at all. The MW definition is accurate. You might try and keep these comments on point.

This is an example of 'headline English', which can differ in a number of ways from normal English usage. The style emphasizes brevity above everything else, and so you will often see short words that would be unusual in normal speech used to replace longer, but more idiomatic, forms.


Privacy issues quash digital wallets
(Privacy issues prevent adoption of digital wallets.)




Probe slams power outage crisis.
(Public inquiry criticizes electrical power interruption)




Fury at Tax hike shocker
(Public irritated by surprise tax increase)




Rail network sabotage causes travel chaos
(Politically-motivated vandalism causes transit inconvenience)




Warring sisters end Walker feud
(Irrelevant celebrities end an uninteresting family argument)


(Three of these headlines are genuine, and two are made up. Feel free to guess which is which).
In this context, 'dubs presidential race a toss-up' simply means 'says that/claims that/is of the opinion that the presidential race is a toss-up'.
A three or four letter word is always preferable to a longer one, even if it is much less commonly used than the word it replaces. As you can also see, these short words nearly always increase (and exaggerate) the impression of drama compared with longer statements.
'Dub' is one the more common substitutes, but also one of the more unnatural for normal speech. Here are a couple of other examples from recent newspapers.


3D device dubbed the Tesla of euthanasia
Soak up sweet wine and sunshine on the island that's been dubbed the Hawaii of Europe.


Your example is slightly unusual in that 'dubs' is used simply to replace a word indicating an opinion. In other words it is a synonym for 'says that', 'states' or 'calls'. The headline-writer could equally have used 'calls' or 'names', which only have one letter more. However it is such a staple of headlines that the sub-editor probably didn't think much about it.
Usually, 'dubs' is used by journalists as a shorthand to refer to a nickname or phrase that has been given to a person or thing. In these cases, "The X dubbed 'Y' is ..." is a shorter way of saying "The X, which some people have taken to referring to as 'Y', is ...". It allows the journalist to not only use a shorter word, but to replace an entire subclause with a single verb.

I use "chaos" in everyday speech, usually when speaking to my dogs about their behavior, and could imagine using "feud" if the need arose.

"Owner slams dog feud chaos shocker"?

Owner dubs dog feud "chaos"? Dogs in owner-vocabulary feud row?

"chaos dogs dogs in food feud"

Lol. You win. ..

Yes, it's in a headline but it is used in many other English sentences. Also, this is the title of an article. -1 Collins Corpus: Time magazine once dubbed him 'the man with the golden ear' for his unerring ability to spot a hit.
Times, Sunday Times (2011)

Relevant xkcd
